# OrientationJ: Problem saving results from OrientationJ vector field macro

Tags: macros, imagej, fiji

I am trying to write a macro for ImageJ that processes the images in the specified folder through the OrientationJ Vector Field plugin, and then saves the outputted results tables into a separate folder. The issue is that when I run the macro, the OrientationJ Vector Field's dialogue box pops up however the results are not saved anywhere. I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly, and it would be much appreciated if someone could help me. The code for my macro is shown below, thanks.

```
dir1 = getDirectory("Choose Source Directory ");
dir2 = getDirectory("Choose Destination Directory ");
list = getFileList(dir1);
setBatchMode(true);
for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    showProgress(i+1, list.length);
    filename = dir1 + list[i];
    if (endsWith(filename, "tif")) {
        open(filename);
        run("8-bit");
        run("OrientationJ Vector Field");
        run("OrientationJ Vector Field", "tensor=2.0 gradient=0 radian=on vectorgrid=50 vectorscale=80.0 vectortype=0 vectoroverlay=off vectortable=on ");
        saveAs("Results", dir2+list[i]+".csv");
        close();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using another ImageJ-plugin, such as "Orientations_"?
https://www.gluender.de/Miscellanea/MiscTexts/UtilitiesText.html#Gl-2020-1
ImageJ-Macro call:
run( "Orientations ", "local diameter=16 indicator" );

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't want to use a different plugin since OrientationJ is my preferred orientation analysis tool. Do you know how to get the macro to save the .csv results? I have seen online that there are others with similar issues, but haven't seen a solution yet.

Comment: If you have the table displayed use: nme = Table.title;
path = "/Users/yourName/Downloads/";
Table.save( path+nme+".csv" );

Answer (score 0):

Update: Issue has been resolved by manually updating OrientationJ to 2.0.5 (from May 2020). In the older versions, the vector field did not work from a macro. The latest version can be found on the OrientationJ website: http://bigwww.epfl.ch/demo/orientationj/

Fiji does not have the latest version of O.J. included and so the latest version needs to manually be installed.